# Problem with loading the hpricot gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, hpricot

I have a problem with loading the hpricot gem.
I'm using it in a rake task and put a `require "hpricot"` in it.
But it doesn't load with a error message:`no such file to load -- hpricot`
But I'll see it in my gem list but don't know why the rake task doesn't recognize it.
Does anybody has experience with that kind of problem with the hpricot gem?

output of `gem list -d hpricot`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

hpricot (0.8.3)
   Author: why the lucky stiff
   Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/hobix
   Homepage: http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/
   Installed at: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8

   a swift, liberal HTML parser with a fantastic lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I forgot to add the hpricot gem to the gem file of my rails app.
After I added the gem to the gemfile and ran a `bundle install` , everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `require 'rubygems'` before requiring hpricot.

Comment: I did it, but still the same result.

Comment: Looks like you are on OSX and there is something wrong with the gem paths. Can you please freeze the gem within the Rails app or to ask the rake task to print _where_ it is looking for gems?

Comment: how can I ask the rake task to print where it is looking for gems?